# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have this extension of UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {

 func resizeImage(newWidth: CGFloat, newHeight: CGFloat? = nil) -> UIImage {

    let scale = newWidth / self.size.width
    let finalHeight = (newHeight == nil) ? self.size.height * scale : newHeight!

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width:newWidth, height: finalHeight), false, self.scale)
    self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: finalHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
 }
}
```

Why is UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext returning nil? Does it have something to do with the image size?

(lldb) po self.size
▿ (3024.0, 4032.0)
  - width : 3024.0
  - height : 4032.0

[image]

Comment: "Why UIGraphicsEndImageContext returns nil? is it something to do with the image size?" Good question. Why don't you answer it? Try a small image size and see!

Comment: Also you can call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` and see whether the context itself is `nil`.

Comment: I´´m calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext and it return nil...

Comment: Well, there you go then.

Comment: A 3024 by 4032 with a scale of 3 (triple resolution device) would have more than 36 million pixels. Do those numbers not scare you just a little?

Comment: This is *very* similar to something I answered yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073021/memory-leak-when-resizing-uiimage/46074959#46074959). Try that code - I'm guessing that if it fails, you need to check why you are setting a height of `nil` (maybe it should be 0?) and then doing computations on the height. And my extension does work? Probably you coded your calculations (particularly height) in such a way that it returned `nil` - which is the default!

Answer (score 7):

Looks like UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is implemented so that it tries to allocate a consecutive region of memory for image buffer. The region is really big and can be as big as 50MB. What happens is that "malloc" call returns null, and the call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions fails silently. The reasons for malloc failure could be different from memory shortage to memory fragmentation, this is the reason why the reproduction of this problem is not consistent.

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem too. The first time `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` return nil, but the same code, on the second time, can get the return data. At last I found, if the view's subview's  size is zero, this problem will happen. So I suggest you to check and remove the view's subviews which size is zero. I hope that work for you!

Comment: your answer is very helpful...!